# Toit: Cannot import `hc_sr04`

Tags: toit

I cannot import `hc_sr04` in my Toit code. I get the error: `Package for prefix 'rmt' not found`. How can I fix the `rmt` import issue?

I have installed the `hc_sr04` package.

```
$ toit pkg install github.com/lask/toit-hc-sr04@2.0.0
```

I try importing it in my code: `main.toit`

```
import hc_sr04


main:
  print "Start"
```

When I run it, I get the error: `Package for prefix 'rmt' not found`

```
$ toit run --device <UUID> main.toit
<pkg:toit-hc-sr04>/driver.toit:1:8: error: Package for prefix 'rmt' not found
import rmt
       ^~~
<pkg:toit-hc-sr04>/driver.toit:41:14: error: Unresolved type: 'Channel'
  echo_ /rmt.Channel
             ^~~~~~~
<pkg:toit-hc-sr04>/driver.toit:42:17: error: Unresolved type: 'Channel'
  trigger_ /rmt.Channel
                ^~~~~~~
<pkg:toit-hc-sr04>/driver.toit:45:21: error: Unresolved type: 'Signals'
  rmt_signals_ /rmt.Signals
                    ^~~~~~~
<pkg:toit-hc-sr04>/driver.toit:56:20: error: Unresolved identifier: 'Channel'
    trigger_ = rmt.Channel trigger --output --idle_level=0
                   ^~~~~~~
<pkg:toit-hc-sr04>/driver.toit:57:17: error: Unresolved identifier: 'Channel'
    echo_ = rmt.Channel echo --input
                ^~~~~~~
<pkg:toit-hc-sr04>/driver.toit:62:24: error: Unresolved identifier: 'Signals'
    rmt_signals_ = rmt.Signals 1
                       ^~~~~~~
Compilation failed.
```

---

```
$ toit version
+---------+------------+
| VERSION |    DATE    |
+---------+------------+
| v1.20.1 | 2022-05-03 |
+---------+------------+
```

- `package.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  hc_sr04:
    url: github.com/lask/toit-hc-sr04
    version: ^2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the package manager.

The `hc-sr04` package depends on an sdk environment `^2.0.0-alpha.1`. However, you are running with `v1.20.1`.

In theory, the package manager should not have given you that package, but an older version that doesn't have this environment requirement. That said, it looks like older `hc-sr04` packages also need the RMT (ESP32's remote-control peripheral).

How to fix:

- either switch to the open-source version (https://github.com/toitlang/jaguar) which already has the RMT, or
- implement the `hc-sr04` driver yourself without using the RMT.

I recently did this as an exercise:

```
// Distributed under BSD0. (see my profile).
import gpio

TRIGGER ::= 21  // Change to your trigger pin.
ECHO ::= 22  // Change to your echo pin.

measure_distance trigger echo:
  trigger_start := Time.monotonic_us
  trigger.set 1
  while Time.monotonic_us < trigger_start + 10:
    // Do nothing while waiting for the 10us.
  trigger.set 0

  while echo.get != 1: null
  echo_start := Time.monotonic_us
  while echo.get == 1: null
  echo_end := Time.monotonic_us
  diff := echo_end - echo_start
  return diff / 58

main:
  trigger := gpio.Pin TRIGGER --output
  echo := gpio.Pin ECHO --input
  while true:
    print "measured $(measure_distance trigger echo)cm"
    sleep --ms=50
```

This code is not as precise as the RMT based code, but it's not bad either.

Comment: FYI: The solution I chose was to use your code. Thanks!